# Query last write time on Azure DevOps repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, ado

I need to query last write time for files in multiple folders on Azure DevOps repository.

File paths, and last write times would then get written into a file.

This is supposed to run on ADO pipeline.

I attempted to automate this task by adding a powershell task to the pipeline, however when the agents checks out the repository, last write times get overwritten with last commit time.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this via ADO API? So far I only found a way to return file paths, without the last write times.
I have used the following format with ADO API:

```
$repoUrl = [string]::Format("https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/git/repositories/{2}/items?recursionLevel=Full&api-version=7.0", $orgName, $projectId, $repoId)
```

- Tried doing it via PS
- Tried doing it via ADO API

Comment: I think you should look into the queryparameters of this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#uri-parameters espeacially 'latestProcessedChange' could be of interrest for you

Comment: I tried it with latestProcessedChange, however you still cannot see the last write date of the file. You just see the commit ID, comitter name etc.

Comment: That is what you want. I just tried the same API and it includes the author and commit date when using `latestProcessedChange=true`.

Comment: Suppose you modify a file on your machine at 1:00. Then you commit the file at 2:00. Then you push the commit at 3:00. What time would you consider the "last write time" in AzDo?

Comment: Hmm thats actually a good question. I would like to get the first time, ie. when I saved the file on my machine.